# BeautifulSoup4 html parsing returns null

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve the data from the div tag with id="BTCSummary", but cant seem to get any of the number values (last price in particular), the program is returning an empty list rather than the number.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.btcmarkets.net")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

summary = soup.find(id='BTCSummary')

lis = summary.find(class_='last-price')

temp = lis.find(class_='value')

print(temp.contents)
```

output:

```
[]
```

I'm able to retrieve the 'headings' for the numbers, but not the numbers themselves

Comment: paste a copy of the dom too.

Comment: if you `print` `page.content` and manually inspect the console for the given ids, can you locate them there?

Comment: the value is loaded later by js

Comment: No, they're not there either, just comes up as a blank line \n

Comment: Is there a way then to retrieve data from js?

Comment: Use their api or some other source which provides api, there are many free providers.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that!

Comment: here is one to get started `https://poloniex.com/support/api/`

Comment: javaScript uses urls like `https://www.btcmarkets.net/data/market/BTCMarkets/BTC/AUD/tick?_=1513702821298` , `https://www.btcmarkets.net/data/market/BTCMarkets/BTC/AUD/tick?_=1513702821298`

Comment: Try to use any browser simulator to catch the dynamically loaded contents which are in this case the `value` you are after. Selenium can be an option.